# how do I get filename, file handling in assembly

Tags: assembly

I have scratched my brain to limits & searched also on net about file handling in Assembly but I am still confused about it.
I am working on linux shell for creating assembly program in AT&T syntax. Basically I don't understand how to push filename into ebx. Following is the code that confuses me.

```
    section .text
    global _start

    _start:
pop ebx     ; argc (argument count)
pop ebx     ; argv[0] (argument 0, the program name)
pop ebx     ; The first real arg, a filename

mov eax,8       ; The syscall number for creat() (we already have the filename  in ebx)
mov ecx,00644Q  ; Read/write permissions in octal (rw_rw_rw_)
int 80h     ; Call the kernel
            ; Now we have a file descriptor in eax
```

I don't understand, how popping values into ebx is going to help in opening file?
Plz explain these lines. I guess these lines are taking input as we do it in C{e.g. in main(int argc, char *argv[]) }. But I can't correlate with it.

Comment: By the way your code isn't in AT&T syntax, but Intel instead. AT&T syntax is more like: `mov $8, %eax`

Comment: That can't be right, [read this](http://linuxgazette.net/84/hawk.html).

Comment: I wrote a tutorial on getting passed parameters: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/285550-nasm-linux-getting-command-line-parameters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters are passed to other functions in stack. Functions can retrieve them by either accessing to stack by an offset, or popping the values individually.

```
pop ebx
pop ebx
pop ebx
```

Because every pop operation overrides `ebx`'s value ebx keeps the last value popped. So those three instructions are equivalent to:

```
mov ebx, [esp+8] ; esp+0 argc, esp+4 argv, esp+8 first param
```

Comment: The one I showed is taken from a website. I am using AT&T code. One more question- When are these values pushed onto stack? I mean, what I understood is, when I execute ./program_name in the console, the name 'program_name' is pushed. But what about if this program is executed by system & 'program_name' is not passed from CLI.

Comment: It is bedtime over here, will be online after 10 hrs. Thanks 'ssg'!.

Comment: @kriss CLI doesn't execute your program, OS does. CLI just tells the OS to do so. Even without a CLI, OS knows the filename and puts that in `argv[0]`. It's called `execve()` on Linux. You can see its source at: http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/exec.c#n1457

Comment: Note: the `_start:` label is not `call`ed! The stack is like Gunner explains. If you start your program with `main:`, `main` is `call`ed, and the stack is in a different condition, and your code needs to be different. Since you begin with `_start:`, do it like Gunner says.